# autologin to webform not working

Tags: javascript, autologin

Apologies if this sounds naive. I created a html page with a form which logs into another website on submit. I tested this with two websites, its working for one of them (lets call it website A)and not working for the other website(website B).
The difference that I found in the page source of A and B is that website B has an action attribute set on the form, like this:

```html
 <form name="LoginForm" method="post" action="./" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnlogin')" id="LoginForm" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
```

My HTML CODE:

```html
<html><head></head>
  <body style="word-wrap: break-word;">
  <form id="LoginForm" target="_self" method="post" action="website B login page">
    <input type="hidden" name="tbUsername" value="StarFort">
    <input type="hidden" name="tbPassword" value="325starfort306">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
    document.getElementById('LoginForm').submit();
    // once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        if (iframe.src != "Wesite B home page") {
  
            iframe.src = "Wesite B home page";
        }
    }
</script>
    <iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="yes" style="border:0" target="_self" src="Wesite B home page"></iframe>
  

</body></html>
```

Any suggestion on what might be the issue?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you add to your question the `<form>` element of website A?

Comment: This is how the form element of website A looks like:
 <form name="loginForm" action="/ct/ct_logon.asp" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return doValidate()">

Comment: Do you want to submit the form to a certain webpage or execute a javascript function on form submit? I am getting confused.

Comment: Hi,I want to submit the form on the webpage B. My code should be able to fill in the credentials and submit.

Answer (score 0):

The `action` attribute specifies the page to which the form will be submitted. When the form is submitted from website A, it is redirecting to "/ct/ct_logon.asp". However, when the form is submitted from website B, no redirection occurs. To redirect, modify the `action` attribute such that it includes the page to which you are submitting the form entries.

Comment: I cannot cange the action attribute. These are external websites. I am just trying to automate the login process.

Comment: So website B has a login form. You want to implement that form in your website. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: If this is what you want, then find the address to which website B is submitting its form, and place that address inside your form's `action` attribute.